# Devise or Custom authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am a NOOB to Rails 3 and just completed the Ruby-on-Rails tutorial.  This tutorial provided a sound method for logging users in, signing them up and authenticating them.

I started looking for some ready made authentication systems and came across Devise.

Should I be using an off the shelf system or stick with the one I learned in the book?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what you want to do.

Devise is very clear on what it allows to do -or not-. I ended up using Devise for my latest project (and first one in RoR) and Devise is great.

I needed to override many controllers in order to achieve what I needed, but globally, I'm satisfied.

The [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages) has a lot of good tutorials...So does [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devise) ! :)